# How to concatenate seperate digits from a loop into one single integer

Tags: java, string, variables, concatenation

okay so I have an assignment that says i have a string of numbers for example 
"1234 4014 5555 7654" say which is essentially a credit card number. 
They are asking me to convert the string of digits into single integers then concatenate them into 4 lots of 4 digit integers so the string "1234 4014 555 7654" for example will have 4 blocks 
block 1 would be 1234 
which is converted into 1, 2, 3, 4 
which is then concatenated into 1234 as an integer
i have to do this for all the blocks... :(

So far.. i made a for loop as shown below :

```
public static int toInt(String digitString)
{
    int answer = 0;
    int num = 0;
    for (int j = 0; j < digitString.length(); j++){
        num = (int) digitString.charAt(j) - '0';
        System.out.println(num);
    }

    return answer
```

}

and i can successfully convert the string into seperate digits but i have no idea how i can concatenate those digits into 4, 4 digit integers

any help would be much appreciated :)

Answer (score 3, accepted):

I'm not going to do your assignment for you, but I'll tell you this hint: All you need to know to understand and solve this problem is that `Integer.parseInt(s)` for some String s returns s as an integer, and that `s.substring(n, n+1)` returns the (n+1)st character of a String.

For example

```
String s = "1234";
s = s.substring(0, 1); //s = "1"
int val = Integer.parseInt(s); //val = 1
```

And that's it. Now it's just a matter of looping over your String and doing whatever you want with them. I suppose it might be helpful to know that you can assign an integer to a string with:

```
String temp = val + "";
//or
String temp = String.valueOf(val);
```

Comment: i like the idea you have suggested and if i could use that i would, however the assignment description (and i should of added this in my question) says "do Not use any existing java class methods to perform the conversion all at once " 
Does this break the rules? or is it okay?

Comment: I'm not sure what he means by not using java class methods. This problem is impossible without using Java classes (at least String). Maybe he means don't use some class that will do this problem in one line written by somebody else, or whatever. Though I'm not sure.

Comment: okay sweet i might use this method then, 

thankyou for your time :)